# What are the "safe" Emacs user keybinding namespaces to use?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I'd like to set up a number of keybindings globally for all modes. I understand that there are certain Emacs keybinding prefixes that are "reserved" for the user but is there a keybinding prefix that is "safe" across all the different kinds of modes?

Comment: Assuming you're speaking as a user rather than a package writer, one approach I've found fruitful is to pick a key with a global definition I don't use overmuch (e.g., `C-z` for minimize) and rebind that as a global prefix.  I usually push the key I've displaced into the prefix (e.g., put minimize on `C-z C-z` or somesuch) so I can still access it.

Answer (score 1):

Safe for whom? A library or a user?

See the Elisp manual, node [Key Binding Conventions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Conventions.html) for exactly which keys are reserved for users, for major modes, and for minor modes.

As you don't say just what you are doing, it's impossible for us to guess which category your question falls into.

As for a prefix key, you can see that you should not count on using `C-c`, `C-h` or `<f5>` through `<f9>`, if you want your prefix key to be "safe" in all contexts.

Comment: Safe for a user. A keybinding namespace where I can define keybindings as a user without fear that it will conflict with default keybindings or keybindings of modes that I might use.

Comment: A **user** can define *any* keybindings s?he likes. The only way to know whether a given key is defined by default globally or in a given mode is to ask Emacs: `C-h k` (in that mode). Otherwise, you can get some guidance from the Key Bindings Conventions section of the Elisp manual, as I said.

Answer (score 1):

As @drew points out, look at the tips section of the manual for some guidance on key binding conventions. It can be a bit challenging to work out where to bind things, especially when you don't want to possibly interfere with standard bindings or end up having your bindings shadowed etc.

The problem with answering this type of question is that key bindings are very much a matter of personal taste. For example, I see many suggestions that the first thing you should do is redefine the caps lock key to be a ctrl key. This seems like good advice given the ctrl key is often difficult to press in key chord combinations and has the potential to create various strain issues. However, I don't do this because I don't seem to have an issue with Ctrl being where it is and more importantly, I want to have a ctrl key for both my left and right hand to use. I find keyboards with only a single ctrl key far more frustrating than the key being down low and only really accessible to my pinky!

The other thing which can make advice in this area difficult is the variation you get on different platforms and with different desktop environments. Nearly all platforms now have some level of keyboard shortcut mechanism. The problem with this is that in some cases, various key combinations will be 'stolen' by the underlying OS or more often, the desktop environment. This frequently means that to get your ideal emacs environment, you will often need to also tweak your OS or desktop environment as well.

Something which may help is if I describe my approach to addressing this issue. It won't provide you with an exact or specific answer, but it may provide you with some ideas which will help you find the most appropriate solution for your circumstances.

- I run emacs under Linux and OS X. I don't use windows and have never run emacs under windows.
- I try to use a scheme for my key bindings which will work the same across environments. However, my approach is constantly evolving. I only started using OSX a while ago and it has required me to change my scheme a bit to improve the consistency across platforms.
- There are two packages I find very helpful when trying to sort this out. Both are available via MELPA. free-keys and the bind-keys package. The free-keys package can show you what keys are available and the bind-keys has a very useful command describe-persoanl-keybindings, which shows what keys you have bound and in some cases, what the key use to be bound to. I find this an extremely useful command for both planning and diagnosing problems.
- Originally, my approach was to find a global key binding for a command which I seldom or never use, for example C-z => suspend-frame or M-` => tmm-menu-bar and undefine it. I would then define those keys as prefix keys for my own personal keymap and define keys under that.

The advantage to this approach is that I can be fairly confident that nothing will cause my bindings to be shadowed or get redefined and all my bindings are tied to a separate prefix.

- Something I'm experimenting with now is the use of the super and hyper modifiers. In particular, the super modifier has become easily accessible as the 'windows' key on most keyboards and these days, is trivial to configure under most Linux distros. The key position is also close to the position of the 'option' key under OSX.

The only problem with using these keys is that they are frequently used by the OS or desktop environment. In some cases, this is easy fixed us the OS or desktop environment preferences mechanism, but in other situations, it seems the key binding is too tightly coupled with the OS or desktop environment and you cannot change it. The only solution I've found is to conduct a bit of trial and error. However, once you do have it sorted, it is very unlikely that any emacs libraries or features will clobber your bindings and unlikely you are clobbering something you are unaware of. Extremely useful and often overlooked modifiers IMO.

- finally, remember C-h k - this key is essential when trying to work this stuff out.